# Payment via Braintree PayPal always fails iOS

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, braintree

I have opened a ticket about this on [Braintree iOS's GITHub.](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/issues/405) Just hoping to get some help fast. Here goes the issue:

As the title says, my payment (in iOS) always fails. While apparently, the payment in my colleague's work (Android) succeeds.

I followed thoroughly the sample codes and guidelines from here: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/client-side/ios/v4

In iOS, after all the process (Client Token from our Server --> BT SDK --> PayPal browser --> App --> send nonce to our server), the error I get from our server is always:

> PayPal pending payments are not supported.

My backend guy does not know the reason behind this too, he only showed and gave me this log:

```
{
   "errors": {},
   "params": {
       "transaction": {
           "type": "sale",
           "amount": "1",
           "merchantAccountId": "USD",
           "paymentMethodNonce": "80823f63-5ea9-0b8b-67da-0710bd7d9ff1",
           "orderId": "333",
           "descriptor": {
               "name": "company name*myurl.com"
           },
           "options": {
               "submitForSettlement": "true",
               "paypal": {
                   "customField": "custom",
                   "description": "description"
               }
           }
       }
   },
   "message": "Unknown or expired payment_method_nonce.",
   "creditCardVerification": null,
   "transaction": null,
   "subscription": null,
   "merchantAccount": null,
   "verification": null
}
```

And here's what I do in setting up my SDK:

```
private func processPayPalClientToken(_ clientToken: String) {
        SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Please wait...")

        self.braintreeClient = BTAPIClient(authorization: clientToken)

        let payPalDriver = BTPayPalDriver(apiClient: self.braintreeClient)
        payPalDriver.viewControllerPresentingDelegate = self
        payPalDriver.appSwitchDelegate = self

        let request = BTPayPalRequest(amount: self.bookingViewModel.getTotalAmount())
        payPalDriver.requestOneTimePayment(request) { (nonce, error) in
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss(completion: {
                if let error = error {
                    self.showAlert(title: "title...", message: "Error: \(error.localizedDescription).", okayButtonTitle: "OK") { _ in }
                    return
                }

                guard let nonce = nonce else { return }

                self.processNonceToServer(nonce)
            })

        }
    }
```

So... any idea what's the reason behind this? Thanks!

EDIT: Additional info that I found a while ago. The SFSafari browser dismisses itself too soon that's why the nonce I get is always invalid. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the benefits of the others who are experiencing the same issue, check out my closed ticket I filed on Braintree's Github (link above or this: https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/issues/405)

Here's my colleague and I have discovered:

1. We can pay successfully using this CREDIT UNION payment method.
2. BUT we can't pay using PAYPAL BALANCE.
3. The errors like below happens in PayPal Balance option.

> PayPal pending payments are not supported

So the answer in this issue would be: make sure that everything in your client is working and you're using correct and same accounts for the clientToken and the PayPal account you're using to pay.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact 
[support](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact).</sub>

Based on the payment method nonce that you posted in your question, I was able to take a look into our server-side logs to see what the issue is.

Without giving away any specific [API Credentials](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/important-gateway-credentials#api-credentials), it appears as if the server responsible for [generating a client token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/ios/v4#get-a-client-token) in your setup is passing a different Sandbox [merchant ID](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/important-gateway-credentials#merchant-id) than the server responsible for creating the transaction with that payment method nonce, which is leading to an error.

Your server is responsible for generating a client token, which contains the authorization and configuration details that your client needs to initialize the client SDK. When a payment method nonce is created, it is tied to the merchant ID that is specified in the client token authorization. The [merchant ID passed during the Transaction Sale call or other API Calls](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-server/ruby) must match the merchant ID that is tied to that specific payment method nonce, so you will need to fix this discrepancy in your backend code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I'm checking if this answer really answers/helps the issue... What I observed though in my application versus  the Android equivalent of my two projects is that the Safari browser opened by the BT SDK closes too early. While in Android, there's still a last screen (I'll take a screenshot later when I can). The last screen that appears in Android looks like an email confirmation page, it appears too in iOS but only a second. Does this contribute to the issue?

Comment: Bounty shall be given to you, Lairen. Thank you for taking your time to answer this question.